# Redirect Image file not found to Uri with NGinx

Tags: macos, nginx

I'm switching a Laravel Website from Apache (htaccess) to NGinx. I have built an Image Serving that produces a uri with the appropriate parameters for resizing ex : `pics/images/max24h/music_video_red_icon.png`.
I Apache does not find the file it would redirect it to a route `image/images/max24h/music_video_red_icon.png` where an Action in laravel creates and returns the image. In `.htaccess` it works with this code :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^pics(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ /image$1.$2 [R=307,L]
```

Now in NGinx conf, How do I redirect it properly? I tried a lot of suggestions like :

```
# Redirect pics file not found to php laravel route to create the image
location @img_proxy {
    rewrite ^/pics(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ /image$1.$2;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

It does not work at all, the server works if I remove those lines. I'm using Mac High Sierra 10.13.6 . Could it be some config conflict? Here is the full `nginx.conf` :

```
user _www _www;

worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/megalobiz/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        gzip on;
            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";
            gzip_comp_level 6;
            gzip_min_length 1100;
            gzip_buffers 16 8k;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_types
                text/plain
                text/css
                text/js
                text/xml
                text/javascript
                application/javascript
                application/x-javascript
                application/json
                application/xml
                application/xml+rss;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
        #if (!-d $request_filename)
        #{
        #    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
        #}

        # Redirect pics file not found to php laravel route to create the image
        location ~ ^/pics(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ {
            try_files $uri @img_proxy;
        }

        location @img_proxy {
            rewrite ^/pics(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ /image$1.$2;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files      $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)\$ {
            expires 1M;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)\$ {
            expires 7d;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `;`. Test your configuration using `nginx -t`.

Comment: Sorry. I miss it probably by playing with it. Now the Server is working but receive 404 response page with `http://localhost/pics/images/max24h/music_video_red_icon.png`, just like other variations I used. I'm starting to suspect config conflict or priority, I don't know NGinx enough.

Comment: Your `location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)\$` block will prevent Laravel seeing the rewritten `/images/` URI.

Comment: Seems logic. But I removed both cache rules, still 404 page.

Comment: Your apache code is performing an external redirect (307 response) - In order for Nginx to perform an external redirect, you will need to append `redirect` to your `rewrite` statement (for a 302 response). If you need to use a 307, you will need something slightly more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day! The Correct syntax was `rewrite ^/pics(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ /image$1.$2 redirect;`. And for the 307 vs 302 redirect, I think I need temporary, not permanent because the original URI will be always used after the image is created. If you Post and answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the function of the `.htaccess` file and your `rewrite` statement is that Apache will perform an external redirect using a 307 response, while Nginx performs an internal redirect instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

To force Nginx to perform an external redirect, append the `permanent` or `redirect` flag to the `rewrite` statement, which generates a 301 or 302 response respectively.

For example:

```
location @img_proxy {
    rewrite ^/pics(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ /image$1.$2 redirect;
}
```

The difference between a 302 and a 307 response, is that the latter will redirect a POST request method without changing it to a GET.

If you need to redirect POST requests, you will need to capture the relevant parts of the URI with a *regular expression*  `location` or `if` block and use a `return 307` instead.

For example:

```
location @img_proxy {
    if ($uri ~ ^/pics(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$) {
        return 307 /image$1.$2$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks for taking me to the right path.